# how to add filter on button click in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to add filter on image click .Actually there is an icon in my demo **"V"**  consider only first one near  "inject" on header.I apply click event on that .Actually I want to add **orderBy** filter in first column on click of image.
what I did I reverse the array on button click .But may be come condition when my array is not sorted then I need to first sort the given array .That what I am trying to add filter on image click .I try to read documentation of orderBy but there is nothing written how can we use button click event .
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

**Javascript code**

```
$scope.sortdata = function() {
      //alert('--')
      $scope.displayData=$scope.displayData.slice().reverse();
  };
```

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/FqL7g2w5yLEREopY4B10?p=preview
Here my code is working fine when user click image is come ascending and descending order.but when array is not sorted it is not work ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume $scope.sortdata is your click, if so, you can add a filter via:

```
scope.sortdata = function() {
  //alert('--')
  $filter('filterName')(argument1, argument2, etc);
};
```

Remember to inject `$filter` into your controller

Comment: but how to add filter of sorting ..could you please tell me how to sort  .in ascending or descending

Comment: here is my plunker please add for sorting http://plnkr.co/edit/FqL7g2w5yLEREopY4B10?p=preview